# Bootstrap5: Can I override the actual viewport so as to display content according to div size instead

Tags: css, django, sass, django-templates, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 with Django - and have one component of my site that lives on its own page -with a responsive layout that stacks and moves some columns around.

I want to reuse the exact same code for a smaller component that will live on the home page in a div that doesn't take 100% of the viewport. When loading the code, can I trick Bootstrap in thinking the viewport is small so that it displays the 'sm' layout?

I have no idea how to do this - what I'm doing right now is basically duplicating my code like this:

```
{% if compsize=='normal' %}
<full responsive page>
{% elif compsize=='compact' %}
<copy/paste of only the compact version of the full page>
{% endif %}
```

It works, but it's not DRY.

Comment: I believe this is the exact use case for container queries. So you might have to use a custom stylesheet to achieve this. Check if [this](https://youtu.be/3_-Je5XpbqY) helps

Comment: This is exactly it - thanks so much. I'll just have to make use of [bootstrap's containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/) - a section, I guess, I slipped over previously.

Comment: I don't think that will do it as bootstrap containers depend on viewport. You will have to write some custom css